# What is the easiest way to duplicate an existing s3 bucket (excluding data)?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to be able to create a  new bucket which mirror the settings of an existing bucket. What is the best way to do it?

Ideally I want to be able to capture the settings via aws cli and create a new one via command line

Comment: There is no "best way". What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 2):

**Idea 1:** If you type [`aws s3api help`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html) you'll see a lot of `get-bucket-*` commands that provide you with the bucket settings. You can plug these into the `create-bucket` and `put-bucket-*` commands for the target bucket.

pros: fast, can be automated

cons: some work to map all of the get output with put input, process needs to be updated as S3 bucket attributes are extended

**Idea 2:** Amazon's CloudFormer tool can generate a CloudFormation template for resources in your account. You can select the source bucket to generate an independent CloudFormation template and then run that with the aws-cli.

pros: straight forward steps to get a template

cons: requires a several minute GUI process to generate the template, which cannot be automated